# How Does Windows 7 / 10 Taskbar Resize Its Default Height Relative Screen Resolution?

Tags: windows, qt, height, screen-resolution, taskbar

In current Qt/QML the taskbar height is not considered in Windows OS (see: [QTBUG-61232](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61232)).

A kludgy solution I've come up w/ is:

```
height: {
   switch (Screen.desktopAvailableHeight) {
      return 1032 //1080 - 48 px for status bar
   }

   return Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
}
```

The upside is that this appears to be a windows specific issue, so the other displays w/ OS GUI considered, aren't expected to match exactly common screen pixel heights... so for them the case will be passed over and the standard behavior applied.

However, I need that knowledge of how the Windows taskbar resizes itself relative the display (note: I'm ***only*** considering default bottom position / default size of the taskbar upon OS install) in order to fill in the rest of the `switch` for [other common resolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions), i.e. `720`, etc.

How is the Windows taskbar sized relative pixel height of the Screen for recent Windows OSes (Windows 7 / 10)?

For an application running on multiple OSes what is there a cleaner recommended workaround for this?

---

***Additional Notes:***

I searched for this thinking I'd find a preexisting post, but I did not see anything pertinent.

Most related posts were language specific answers of how to get the height of the taskbar in some specific language -- but my problem is the language is broken, so I potentially need more fundamental information on the sizing trend to make a workaround.

Also, the browser `screen.availHeight` [strategy](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_availheight.asp) does not work in this implementation of JS.

Comment: According to the bug report, only the qml version is affected. You could use the c++ one from qtwidgets: [QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry)

Comment: And of course since it is a windows specific issue, you can just use the winapi if you do not want to depend on qtwidgets. A quick google search showed lots of different solutions to do that.